# What does "Error: Unable to records bytes produced to topic as the node is not recognized" indicate?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams application that works fine locally, but when I run it in Docker containers not all data is processed, and I get a lot of repeated errors in the logs about "unable to records bytes produce to topic"

```
18:58:32.647 [kafka-producer-network-thread | my-app-events-processor.splitPackets-cf462b02-f1e3-4ed5-a1e7-acc1f040495b-StreamThread-1-producer] ERROR o.a.k.s.p.i.RecordCollectorImpl - stream-thread [my-app-events-processor.splitPackets-cf462b02-f1e3-4ed5-a1e7-acc1f040495b-StreamThread-1] task [0_0] Unable to records bytes produced to topic my-app.packet.surface by sink node split-server-log as the node is not recognized.
Known sink nodes are [].
18:58:49.216 [kafka-producer-network-thread | my-app-events-processor.splitPackets-cf462b02-f1e3-4ed5-a1e7-acc1f040495b-StreamThread-1-producer] ERROR o.a.k.s.p.i.RecordCollectorImpl - stream-thread [my-app-events-processor.splitPackets-cf462b02-f1e3-4ed5-a1e7-acc1f040495b-StreamThread-1] task [0_0] Unable to records bytes produced to topic my-app.packet.surface by sink node split-server-log as the node is not recognized.
Known sink nodes are [].
18:59:05.981 [kafka-producer-network-thread | my-app-events-processor.splitPackets-cf462b02-f1e3-4ed5-a1e7-acc1f040495b-StreamThread-1-producer] ERROR o.a.k.s.p.i.RecordCollectorImpl - stream-thread [my-app-events-processor.splitPackets-cf462b02-f1e3-4ed5-a1e7-acc1f040495b-StreamThread-1] task [0_0] Unable to records bytes produced to topic my-app.packet.surface by sink node split-server-log as the node is not recognized.
Known sink nodes are [].
19:00:28.484 [my-app-events-processor.splitPackets-cf462b02-f1e3-4ed5-a1e7-acc1f040495b-StreamThread-1] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [my-app-events-processor.splitPackets-cf462b02-f1e3-4ed5-a1e7-acc1f040495b-StreamThread-1] Processed 3 total records, ran 0 punctuators, and committed 3 total tasks since the last update
```

When I run the application, not all data is processed, only some. Some KafkaStream instances produce data, while others only seem to consume it. I expect it to consume JSON data, and produce images (to be used in a Leaflet web-map). However it will only do this for some of the KafkaStream instances.

I don't get this error when I run locally. What does it mean? How can I fix it?

#### Application setup

I have a single application, `events-processors`, written in Kotlin that uses Kafka Streams. The application uses a Kafka Admin instance to create the topics, then launches 4 separate KafkaStream instances using independent Kotlin Coroutines. `events-processors` runs in a Docker container.

The Kafka instance is using Kafka Kraft, and is running in another Docker container on the same Docker network.

I am using

- Kafka 3.3.1
- Kotlin 1.7.20
- docker-compose version 1.29.2
- Docker version 20.10.19
- Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

  - Kernel: Linux 5.10.0-18-amd64
  - Architecture: x86-64

#### Kafka config

Here is the config of one of the KafkaStreams instances:

```
18:38:25.138 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-5 @my-app-events-processor.splitPackets#5] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [my-app-events-processor.splitPackets-d7b897b3-3a10-48d6-95c7-e291cb1839d8-StreamThread-1] Creating restore consumer client
18:38:25.142 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-5 @my-app-events-processor.splitPackets#5] INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values:
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = none
    bootstrap.servers = [http://kafka:29092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = my-app-events-processor.splitPackets-d7b897b3-3a10-48d6-95c7-e291cb1839d8-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer
    client.rack =
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = null
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = false
    internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = true
    isolation.level = read_committed
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 1000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor, class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 45000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

The server config is the Kafka Kraft config, https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/215d4f93bd16efc8e9b7ccaa9fc99a1433a9bcfa/config/kraft/server.properties, although I have changed the advertised listeners.

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
```

#### Docker config

The Docker config is defined in a docker-compose file.

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:

  events-processors:
    image: events-processors
    container_name: events-processors
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "http://kafka:29092"
    networks:
      - my-app-infra-nw
    depends_on:
      - infra-kafka
    secrets:
      - source: my-app_config
        target: /.secret.config.yml

  infra-kafka:
    image: kafka-kraft
    container_name: infra-kafka
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      my-app-infra-nw:
        aliases: [ kafka ]
    volumes:
      - "./config/kafka-server.properties:/kafka/server.properties"
    ports:
      # note: other Docker containers should use 29092
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9093:9093"
```

Comment: Kafka is not an HTTP protocol. Try removing that prefix from your config

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer - I've removed `http://` and restarted, but I'm still seeing the same error, and not all messages are being processed.

Comment: I found a related issue, it seems that the log message is related to a newer version of Kafka https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-14282

Comment: Okay, then upgrade your kotlin app dependencies

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm on the latest version of everything.

Comment: Oh, thought you meant that you are only getting the log because your app is being ran against a newer version of the broker than your client

Comment: I recently got the same warning message when upgrading from 3.2.1 to 3.3.1.